# Symfony project on Xampp returning 500 internal server errors

Tags: php, mysql, apache, symfony, xampp

I have a social networking project developed by a team of developers. I am attempting to run it on my localhost via Xampp and have got the site up to a basic html version displaying some static pages. At this point, I am receiving many internal server errors and I would like to query if the reasons behind this is my server not configured correctly. I do not have experience with servers and have spent quite some time clicking through the document below. Having noticed many "access denied" errors, I am assuming it is server configuration. I have also been searching through my apache file to figure it out but no success.

> [Sat Jul 29 19:36:54.460754 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10816:tid 492]
>   AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name [Sat Jul 29 19:36:54.591630 2017]
>   [core:warn] [pid 10816:tid 492] AH00098: pid file
>   C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of
>   previous Apache run? [Sat Jul 29 19:36:54.709621 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid
>   10816:tid 492] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does
>   NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Sat Jul 29
>   19:36:55.727316 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10816:tid 492] AH00455:
>   Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations [Sat Jul 29 19:36:55.727316 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice]
>   [pid 10816:tid 492] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7
>   2016 11:13:22 [Sat Jul 29 19:36:55.727316 2017] [core:notice] [pid
>   10816:tid 492] AH00094: Command line:
>   'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache' [Sat Jul 29
>   19:36:55.730318 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10816:tid 492] AH00418:
>   Parent: Created child process 6844 [Sat Jul 29 19:36:57.050472 2017]
>   [ssl:warn] [pid 6844:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server
>   certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Sat
>   Jul 29 19:36:57.255467 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6844:tid 540] AH01909:
>   www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which
>   matches the server name [Sat Jul 29 19:36:57.296495 2017]
>   [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6844:tid 540] AH00354: Child: Starting 150
>   worker threads. [Sat Jul 29 19:37:40.131691 2017] [authz_core:error]
>   [pid 6844:tid 1844] [client ::1:57744] AH01630: client denied by
>   server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/app/,
>   referer: //http://localhost/vabble/ [Sat Jul 29 19:37:40.241477
>   2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1844] [client ::1:57744]
>   AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/src/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/ [Sat Jul 29 19:37:57.587627 2017] [:error] [pid
>   6844:tid 1828] [client ::1:57752] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database
>   'symfony'' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(43):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array)\n#1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver.php(45):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....',
>   'root', NULL, Array)\n#2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(360):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', NULL,
>   Array)\n#3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(429):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()\n#4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(389):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabas in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 103, referer: http://localhost/vabble/Vabble-code/ [Sat Jul
>   29 19:43:56.135682 2017] [:error] [pid 6844:tid 1852] [client
>   ::1:57884] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'symfony'' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(43):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array)\n#1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver.php(45):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....',
>   'root', NULL, Array)\n#2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(360):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', NULL,
>   Array)\n#3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(429):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()\n#4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(389):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabas in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Vabble\Vabble-code\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 103, referer: http://localhost/vabble/Vabble-code/ [Sat
>   Jul 29 20:03:08.221738 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1852]
>   [client ::1:58357] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/app/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/ [Sat Jul 29 20:03:08.271769 2017]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1852] [client ::1:58357] AH01630:
>   client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/src/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/ [Sat Jul 29 20:06:49.828650 2017]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1828] [client ::1:58396] AH01630:
>   client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/app/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/ [Sat Jul 29 20:18:45.773285 2017]
>   [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1868] [client ::1:58525] AH01630:
>   client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/app/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/
>   **[Sat Jul 29 20:18:45.833328 2017]** [authz_core:error] [pid 6844:tid 1868] [client ::1:58525] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/Vabble/Vabble-code/src/, referer: http://localhost/vabble/

Comment: "client denied by server configuration" looks like there is something not properly configured on the 'server'.

Comment: Having spent time reading through it all i believed it to be but,,, pin pointing the why is being quite the trouble.

Comment: "Unknown database 'symfony'' . check parameters.yml and change the DB credentials.

Answer (score 1):

based on this line:
`PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array)\n`

and the message: `Unknown database 'symfony'`

It appears you haven't correctly set the `app/config/parameters.yml` file for your database.

You'll need to figure out your MySQL root user and pass, then from the command line create a user with access to the database you will use for your Symfony project. Then run these commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
******
CREATE DATABASE vabble;
use mysql;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON vabble.* TO 'james'@'192.168.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Then edit your `app/config/parameters.yml` file like so:

```
parameters:
    database_host:     localhost
    database_name:     vabble
    database_user:     james
    database_password: mypass
```

Then from the Symfony project's root folder you can run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

That should setup everything for you. You can read about all this at the Symfony docs here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#a-simple-example-a-product

Comment: parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null

From your comment. Am i correct in stating that my DB name is in fact wrong? Here are you current parameters.

Comment: James, it's not that the DB name is wrong, you could call it 'symfony' as well, then use `create database symfony` instead. I just called it `vabble` based on your project name. You can use the MySQL command `show databases;` to list all the databases, and then `use vabble;` to change to the `vabble` database; and `describe vabble` to describe the tables. These are all standard MySQL commands.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. 

By changing the parameters file within the already established project itself, then creating a doctrine database in symfonys php, it should then run the platform via my local host which i defined in the parameters file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, previously you had configured for a 'symfony' database which didn't exist, and using the `root` user to connect with a `null` password - which would never work.

Comment: If that was the correct answer James, can you click the checkmark by my answer. This helps people when they search on SO for answers.

Comment: I will indeed once i complete above. Work inhibits me from doing more work than I would like. This weekend I will tick if it works!

Answer (score 0):

The first fatal error looks to be `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'symfony''`.

Double check your database connections in Symfony and ensure that you have the database accessible in your local environment.